# %pre scriptlet failed error for yum package install

Tags: linux, centos7, rpm, yum, scriptlet

While installing package using yum, i get following error:

```
$ yum install <rpm_name> -v -y

error: %pre(<rpm_name>) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package <rpm_name>
Warning: scriptlet or other non-fatal errors occurred during transaction.
Verifying : <rpm_name> 1/1
What is this? <rpm_name>
VerifyTransaction time: 0.003
Transaction time: 0.139
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out there was some issue with rpm db. The issue resolved after rebuild rpm DB, referred this link: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rebuilding-corrupted-rpm-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is error in the `rpm` package itself. If you did this package check preinstallation script. If not you can contact the package creator and ask him to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Download that rpm package a run:

```
rpm -qp --scripts <rpmname>.rpm
```

This will give you the content of the scriptlet assigned to this package. RPM is trying to execute and **somewhere** there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

For me in RHEL the solution was running this code:

```
getent group cgred >/dev/null || groupadd cgred
```

Found it here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/62728